# TypeError: this.setState.darkMode is not a function when trying to implement dark mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been doing some research on how to implement dark mode without using hooks.  Unfortunately, I could not find any examples.  However, I tried to implement it with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { CountryList } from "./Components/Card-List/CountryList";
import { SearchBox } from "./Components/Search-box/Search-Box";
import "./Countries.styles.css";

class Countries extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      searchField: "",
      regionField: "",
      darkMode: false,
    };
    this.setDarkMode = this.setDarkMode.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((all) => this.setState({ countries: all, regions: all }));
  }
  setDarkMode(e) {
    this.setState.darkMode((prevMode) => !prevMode);
  }
  render() {
    const { countries, searchField, regionField, darkMode } = this.state;
    const filterCountries = countries.filter(
      (country) =>
        country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) &&
        country.region.toLowerCase().includes(regionField.toLowerCase())
    );

    return (
      <div className={darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
        <nav>
          <h1 className="header">Where in the World</h1>
          <button onClick={this.setDarkMode}>Toggle Mode</button>
          <h1>{darkMode ? "Dark Mode" : "Light Mode"}</h1>
        </nav>

        <div className="Input">
          <SearchBox
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search a Country"
            handlechange={(e) =>
              this.setState({
                searchField: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />

          <SearchBox
            type="regions"
            placeholder="Filter by Regions"
            handlechange={(e) =>
              this.setState({
                regionField: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />
        </div>
        <CountryList countries={filterCountries} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Countries;
```

The error I am getting is this.setState.darkMode is not a function.  Not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.  Implementing this with hooks seems quite straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.setState` is a function, I think you trying to use [`setState` with callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) like so:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ darkMode: !prevState.darkMode }));
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setState is a function to update the state property of your Class Component in react. So you cannot access darkMode property using this.setState.darkMode. If you want to read darkMode property then you have to use:

```
let isDarkMode = this.state.darkMode
```

if you want to set darkMode property then you have to use:

```
this.setState({darkMode: true})
```

Now if you want reverse your darkMode property then you should use:

```
this.setState((prevState) => { darkMode: !prevState.darkMode });
```